# How to validate or compare string by omitting certain part of it

Tags: c#, string

I have a string as below

*"a1/type/**xyz**/parts"*

The part where 'xyz' exists is dynamic and varies accordingly at any size. I want to compare just the two strings are equal discarding the 'xyz' portion exactly.

For example I have string as below

*"a1/type/**abcd**/parts"*

Then my comparison has to be successful

I tried with regular expression as below. Though my knowledge on regular expressions is limited and it did not work. Probably something wrong in the way I used.

```
var regex = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}/\[a-zA-Z]{16}/\[0-9a-zA-Z]/\[a-z]{5}/$";
var result = Regex.Match("mystring", regex).Success;
```

Another idea is to get substring of first and last part omitting the unwanted portion and comparing it.

The comparison should be successful by discarding certain portion of the string with effective code.

**Comparison successful cases**

string1: *"a1/type/**21412ghh**/parts"*

string2: *"a1/type/**eeeee122ghh**/parts"*

**Comparison failure cases:**

string1: *"a1/type/**21412ghh**/parts"*

string2: *"a2/type/**eeeee122ghh**/parts/mm"*

In short *"a1/type/**abcd**/parts"* in this part of string the non-bold part is static always.

Comment: Does "a1/type/abcd/xyz/parts" succeed?

Comment: Can you post more test cases?

Comment: No it should not. Only the xyz, abc portion keeps varying. Rest of the string is constant

Comment: Constant but unknown at compile time, arent they?

Comment: Is there always 4 blocks? always separated with `/`? The dynamic part is always the third one?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: We definitely need more testcases here. To help you along: (1) `a1/type//parts` (2) `a1/type/\\/parts` (3) `a1/type/                           /parts` (this was supposed to have 10+ spaces but SO seems to truncate it) (4) `a1/type/:::/parts` How do these compare to the xyz variant? I'm trying to understand if you're comparing this string by itself, or if you also have implicit expectations that the strings need to e.g. be valid filepaths.

Comment: Why is the first invalid case invalid?

Comment: "xyz", "abc" variant need not be considered. Just discard them

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you've listed `a1/type/21412ghh/parts` as both a success and a failure.

Comment: @Flater the fail one has more sections

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: @Jamiec: Ah I misunderstood. I thought these were listings of success/fail matches to the earlier xyz and abcd variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, you could do this using regex, and pull apart the string. But you have a specified delimiter, just use `String.Split`:

```
bool AreEqualAccordingToMyRules(string input1, string input2)
{
    var split1 = input1.Split('/');
    var split2 = input2.Split('/');
    return split1.Length == split2.Length  // strings must have equal number of sections
       && split1[0] == split2[0] // section 1 must match
       && split1[1] == split2[1] // section 2 must match
       && split1[3] == split2[3] // section 4 must match
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compare the last part `/mm` after `/parts` -> `a1/type/21412ghh/parts` and `a1/type/21412ghh/parts/valval` match

Comment: @Chrᴉz Those were not meant to pass according to the question (see Comparison failure cases)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Split` (to get parts) and *Linq* (to exclude 3d one)

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string string1 = "a1/type/xyz/parts";
  string string2 = "a1/type/abcd/parts";

  bool result = string1
    .Split('/')                    // string1 parts
    .Where((v, i) => i != 2)       // all except 3d one
    .SequenceEqual(string2         // must be equal to 
       .Split('/')                 // string2 parts 
       .Where((v, i) => i != 2));  // except 3d one
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small programm using string functions to compare the parts before and after the middle part:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CutOutMiddle("a1/type/21412ghh/parts"));
        Console.WriteLine("True: " + CompareNoMiddle("a1/type/21412ghh/parts", "a1/type/21412ghasdasdh/parts"));
        Console.WriteLine("False: " + CompareNoMiddle("a1/type/21412ghh/parts", "a2/type/21412ghh/parts/someval"));
        Console.WriteLine("False: " + CompareNoMiddle("a1/type/21412ghh/parts", "a1/type/21412ghasdasdh/parts/someappendix"));
    }
    private static bool CompareNoMiddle(string s1, string s2)
    {
        var s1CutOut = CutOutMiddle(s1);
        var s2CutOut = CutOutMiddle(s2);
        return s1CutOut == s2CutOut;
    }

    private static string CutOutMiddle(string val)
    {
        var fistSlash = val.IndexOf('/', 0);
        var secondSlash = val.IndexOf('/', fistSlash+1);
        var thirdSlash = val.IndexOf('/', secondSlash+1);
        var firstPart = val.Substring(0, secondSlash);
        var secondPart = val.Substring(thirdSlash, val.Length - thirdSlash);

        return firstPart + secondPart;
    }
}
```

returns

```
a1/type/parts
True: True
False: False
False: False
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should cover your case, as said by others, if you have a delimiter use it. In the function below you could change `int skip` for `string ignore` or something similar and within the comparison loop `if(arrayStringOne[i] == ignore) continue;`.

```
   public bool Compare(string valueOne, string valueTwo, int skip) {
      var delimiterOccuranceOne = valueOne.Count(f => f == '/');
      var delimiterOccuranceTwo = valueTwo.Count(f => f == '/');
      if(delimiterOccuranceOne == delimiterOccuranceTwo) {
          var arrayStringOne = valueOne.Split('/');
          var arrayStringTwo = valueTwo.Split('/');
          for(int i=0; i < arrayStringOne.Length; ++i) {
            if(i == skip) continue; // or instead of an index you could use a string
            if(arrayStringOne[i] != arrayStringTwo[i]) {
                return false;
            }
          }
          return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }

  Compare("a1/type/abcd/parts", "a1/type/xyz/parts", 2);
```